# Canonical map from coproduct

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to learn some category theory, and I can't figure out what "canonical map" means here. If $\mathcal{C}$ is some category and $X\sqcup X$ is the coproduct of some object $X\in\mathcal{C}$ with itself, what is the canonical map $X\sqcup X\to X$?

My only guess is that, since $X\sqcup X$ is the coproduct, there's a unique map $f: X\sqcup X\to X$ such that $f\circ\iota = 1_X$ where $1_X: X\to X$ is the identity and $\iota: X\to X\sqcup X$ is the map that comes along with $X\sqcup X$ being the coproduct. But, I'm unsure if this is what is meant by the canonical map.

Comment: There is not just *one* canonical map $X \to X \sqcup X$ (see also the answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are two maps $\iota_1: X\to X\sqcup X$  and $\iota_2: X\to X\sqcup X$, which are the inclusions of $X$ as each of the two factors of $X \sqcup X$.

With this in mind, the map $f: X\sqcup X\to X$ such that $f \circ \iota_n = 1_X$ for both inclusions is a very canonical map. It's often called the co-diagonal, because it's dual to the diagonal map into a product $\Delta :Y \to Y \times Y$